# Camel Bean Lifecycle strategies?

Tags: apache-camel

I have a camel route like the one showed below.  How can I set up Camel to create a new instance of CodeRunner each time the route is run?

```
        public void configure() {
            from("activemq:queue:foo?asyncConsumer=true&concurrentConsumers=10")
                    .bean(new codeRunner(), "runCode")
                    .to("stream:out");
        }
```

Comment: Are you using spring/blueprint for running camel ?

Comment: At the moment no,but this solution is a work-in-progress.   Is that what I have to do to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean "each time a route is run" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use scope="prototype" on your bean. Here some example. Route:

```
from("timer://foo?period=30s")
            .setBody(simple("bean:test?method=getDate"))
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Body:${body}");
```

Bean:

```
<bean id="test" class="my.test.package.Test" scope="prototype"  />
```

Code:

```
public class Test {

final Timestamp date;

public Test() {
    this.date = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
}

public Timestamp getDate() {
    return date;
}
```

}

Output:

```
2018-11-13 16:45:07,372 | INFO  | #6 - timer://foo | route4                           | 98 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.3 | Body:2018-11-13 16:45:07.37
2018-11-13 16:45:37,371 | INFO  | #6 - timer://foo | route4                           | 98 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.3 | Body:2018-11-13 16:45:37.37
2018-11-13 16:46:07,371 | INFO  | #6 - timer://foo | route4                           | 98 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.3 | Body:2018-11-13 16:46:07.371
2018-11-13 16:46:37,375 | INFO  | #6 - timer://foo | route4                           | 98 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.3 | Body:2018-11-13 16:46:37.375
```